# about Fourier transform. graph of frequency over amplitude

Tags: fourier-series, transformation

I want to compute the Fourier transform for the function $f(x)=\sin{x}$. 
The first question is: the Fourier transform is $\pi$?

$$a_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}{\sin{x}\cos{nx}}=0$$
$$b_n=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}{\sin{x}\sin{nx}}=\pi,\mbox{ for }n=1 \mbox{and for the other values of }n \mbox{ is }  0$$

The second question is how can I draw the graph of **frequency versus amplitude?**

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean "amplitude versus frequency".  (I.e., the graph where "frequency" is the horizontal component and "amplitude" is the vertical component.)

Comment: Yes, amplitude versus frequency

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of silly:

$$\sin(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n \cos(nx) + \sum_{n\geq 1} b_n\sin(nx).$$

Clearly, $\sin(x)=\sin(x)$, so $b_1=1$ and everything else is 0.

From the coefficient formula, just double check that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin(x)^2dx=\pi$.

Comment: So, the Fourier Series has only one factor: $\pi$?
Can you tell me something about the graph of frequency over amplitude?